# Кнопки блока "Поделиться" открываются в новой вкладке

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Почему иконки открывают группы в новой вкладке а не в попап окне?

И ещё при добавлении `data-limit="9"` лимит срабатывает, но при клике на кнопку со спрятанными иконками, она не открывается, а подтягивает страницу вверх... [Пример](https://premiuminter.net/magazin/product/view/14/372)

Comment: Пример чего это? Дополните описание, ничего не понятно.

Comment: Как пример "чего этого"? Я же о кнопках пишу "поделится" от [яндекс](https://tech.yandex.ru/share/). При клике на иконку, должно открываться попап окно, а в моём случае происходит переход на новую вкладку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На странице используется устаревшая библиотека mootools. Она переопределяет встроенные функции JavaScript, в результате чего код начинает работать некорректно.

Можно попробовать обновить mootools до последней версии, но я бы рекомендовал отказаться от этой библиотеки вовсе.

Comment: Роман, благодарю, действительно проблема в mootools... После отключения библиотеки, кнопки начали работать как положено! Но зато другие компоненты на сайте перестали без mootools работать... Буду думать как решить, спасибо за правильное направление!